# Iterate over list of class objects - 'pythonic' way

Tags: python

I have a list `test_cases` with class objects. Every object has an attribute called `ident`.
I want to iterate over all objects from list and do something with value under `ident`

This is my code:

```
class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, title, ident, description):
        self.title = title
        self.ident = ident
        self.description = description

test_cases = []
test_cases.append(TestCase(**tc_dict))

i = 0
while i != len(test_cases):
    print(test_cases[i].ident)
    i += 1
```

It works fine, but what I want to ask, if there is a more 'pythonic' way to do that.

Comment: could you provide the test_cases values??(an example of the list)

Comment: Miraculously, I can't find a past SO question about this; nevertheless, it's been discussed at length, e.g. this talk from PyCon 2013. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the objects directly (as opposed to iterating over their indexes):

```
for test_case in test_cases:
    print test_case.ident
```

This is the generic way, and should be used 99% of the time when you want to loop over objects. It works perfectly here and is probably the ideal solution.

If you ever do need the indexes, you should use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, test_case in enumerate(test_cases):
    print index, test_case.ident
```

It's still looping over the objects, but it's simultaneously receiving their indexes from `enumerate`.

---

**In your particular use case**, there is another option though. If you have *a lot* of objects, it might be slow to print them out one by one (calling `print` is rather expensive). If performance turns out to be an issue, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the values beforehand, and then print it all out once:

```
print '\n'.join(tc.ident for tc in test_cases)
```

I personally recommend the first method, and would only refer to the latter when you need to print out *a lot* of stuff and actually can see the performance issue with your naked eye.

Comment: nice one Markus, I guess adding a check hasattr(object, 'attribute') in

    print '\n'.join(tc.ident for tc in test_cases)
will be safe.

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't randomly have objects of different type in your list. OP's example has `TestCase` class, so if you mix in objects that don't duck along with `TestCase`, it's quite likely supposed to raise an error.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can replace your while loop by a for loop

```
for i in range(len(test_cases)):
    print test_cases[i].indent
```

However, looping over an index and accessing an element by using that index is often a code smell in python. Better would simply be to loop over the elements

```
for test_case in test_cases:
    print test_case.indent
```